# Get property with largest index key in object

Tags: javascript, jquery

From the following object, how can I get the 'air' reading from the property with largest index key i.e. 4? (30.9)

```
{
  1: {
    air: "31.2",
    evap: "25.3",
    t_condenser: "43.8"
  },
  2: {
    air: "31.1",
    evap: "25.3",
    t_condenser: "43.6"
  },
  3: {
    air: "31.0",
    evap: "25.3",
    t_condenser: "43.5"
  },
  4: {
    air: "30.9",
    evap: "25.2",
    t_condenser: "43.3"
  }
}
```

I have tried the following, to try to get the last key, but it just reads undefined:

```
$.getJSON("handler.php?action=fetchLAE", function(data){

  console.log(data.length);

});
```

Comment: That's an object, not an array. Also it's not a "JSON array" either. JSON is a string format, not a data structure.

Comment: Why use an object for this? Why not use an array? Then instead of a scan, it's just `data[data.length-1].air`.

Answer (score 2):

Note: The data is badly formatted. That is what an array is for, your API returns an Object.

Solution: find the highest key in data (which is an Object):

```
data[Object.keys(data).sort().pop()].air
```

Explanation:

```
Object.keys(data)
```

Get all the properties as an array e.g. [1,4,3,2].

Now we sort it ascending and take the last:

```
.sort().pop()
```

So we take this property out of the object, and take its air value:

```
data[4].air
```

http://jsbin.com/setibevozu/edit?console

Answer (score 2):

You can obtain the keys of the object with Object.keys() and then use Math.max to get the highest one.

```js
var json = {
  1: {
    air: "31.2",
    evap: "25.3",
    t_condenser: "43.8"
  },
  2: {
    air: "31.1",
    evap: "25.3",
    t_condenser: "43.6"
  },
  3: {
    air: "31.0",
    evap: "25.3",
    t_condenser: "43.5"
  },
  4: {
    air: "30.9",
    evap: "25.2",
    t_condenser: "43.3"
  }
};


var maxKey = Math.max(...Object.keys(json));
var lastElementAir = json[maxKey].air;

console.log(lastElementAir);
```

Comment: Just a side note, this answer uses the spread operator which is only available in ES6+. Equivalent in ES5: `Math.max.apply(Math, +Object.keys(json))`.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a valid JSON, but a javascript object.

You can make use of the `Object.keys` function to get the object properties and then get to the last element or property using the length property.

`console.log(obj[Object.keys(obj).length].air);`

```js
var obj = {
1: {
air: "31.2",
evap: "25.3",
t_condenser: "43.8"
},
2: {
air: "31.1",
evap: "25.3",
t_condenser: "43.6"
},
3: {
air: "31.0",
evap: "25.3",
t_condenser: "43.5"
},
4: {
air: "30.9",
evap: "25.2",
t_condenser: "43.3"
}
};

console.log(obj[Object.keys(obj).length].air);
```

Comment: This assumes that the object only contains continuous numeric keys and starts at 1.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫, yes that's what the data contains in the OP.